# Insert buttons on a picture on mouse hover and image darken

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I want the image to be darkened a little bit when the mouse is hovered on it (Overlay?). Then, the buttons like in the picture should appear when hover, then if mouse is hovered on one button, it should turn to red (just like picture), and image description text should appear under the buttons (as the picture), then if one button is clicked it should take us to a new URL (Say, if the button is clicked, it takes us to the www.google.com), can anyone provide any code? I have no idea how to do that.

[image]

Comment: If you don't know how to do it the first problem you have is that you don't understand HTML, CSS or JavaScript. To address that, you first need to learn. There are many tutorials around the internet, use a search engine of your choice to find one and make a start. We're not a free coding service, we're only here to help you with your programming problems (once you've made an effort and can clearly communicate the problem(s) you're facing in implementing your own solution). Incidentally, you've been a member of this site for 8 months, asked 14 questions and still don't know the site rules?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: SO is not elance.com

Comment: Learn from these (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects) and try it yourself, if still stuck paste code and we will help you with it

Comment: You can do all of this with CSS and HTML. The basic idea is that you will have the overlay that contains the buttons hidden by default, and have it display on :hover. Also change the background color of the button on the button :hover. This is a very easy thing to do, you should be able to figure it out in less than an hour. 

http://www.codeitpretty.com/2013/06/how-to-use-css-hover-effects.html

Comment: Thank you @ArpitGoyal that's wonderful.

Comment: Thank you @mhodges . I'll go through it.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl Welcome, we can not code for you but we can always guide you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.try this. I only concerned about your main points.hope this will work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

div.contain{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 667px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://dancingaspen.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/coffee-shop-mug.jpg);
}

div.mask{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position:relative;
  opacity: 0;

}

.zoom{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: monospace;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.description{
 
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 30%;
  top:410px;
  left: 12%;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-family: zapfino;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}


</style>
<body>

<div class="contain">
 <div class="mask"></div>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="zoom">ZOOM</a>
    <div class="description">your description here</div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contain").mouseenter(function(){
      $(".mask").animate({opacity:0.5},1000);
      $(".zoom").fadeIn(1500);
      $(".description").fadeIn(1500);
    });

     $(".contain").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".mask").animate({opacity:0},1000);
       $(".zoom").fadeOut();
      $(".description").fadeOut();
    });
   });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

just copy, paste and run.

Answer (score 0):

Darkening images can be done with straight css using the 'hover' setting.
select your picture (or preferably the div containing the image) and set div:hover to a lower opacity such as opacity:0.5;

If you want to darken the image without having a dark background, you can set the image as the div's background

```
<parent div>
   <child div>

.parent {background: 'images/image.jpg';}
  .child {background-color: black; opacity:0;}
  .child:hover {opacity:0.7;}
```